# Openerp help me to remove this

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Friends,
Need to remove this option from pop up `manyone` fields. (not in all `fields`.some fields need to remove this feature).i used `widget="selection"`.then my `domain filter` not working.so please help me to find a solution.

[image: Create and Edit option]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module for `openerp 6.1` to remove the create and edit option(in the `openerp` apps site search for web remove) from the default selection of `many2one` field. You can use this as an example and create you own module. or you can modify the base codes goto your server, then navigate to `openerp/addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js` and remove the quick create functionality defined from the line number `2860`.

This is the Same answer that I have given in  `openerp` help site.

Comment: Thanks AnomA..i removed web from openerp 1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem, but I solved it easily.

You need to change your web add-ons.

Please follow the step:

1. Go to: web/static/src/js
2. open the file: `view_form.js`
3. Go to line number 2958 or you can find `label: _t` ("Create and
   Edit..."),
4. comment it

Enjoy, you can now see in your many2one fields don't have 'Create and Edit'

Note : This will affect every many2one field.

Answer (score 0):

In v7 you can use the answer as suggested in http://help.openerp.com/question/16498/how-to-disable-create-and-edit-from-from-a-menu/

```
<form string="My form" create="false">
```

I had this problem in v6.1 though, so I created a new option so that I could apply it to only some fields (not all fields as suggested by @Bipin)

```
<form string="My form" options='{"no_create": true}'>
```

and changed web/static/src/js/view_form.js

```
     // Hack: check for new "no_create" option:
     if (self.get_definition_options().no_create === undefined || !self.get_definition_options().no_create) {
     // the rest of the code stays asis:

        // quick create
        var raw_result = _(data.result).map(function(x) {return x[1];});
        if (search_val.length > 0 &&
            !_.include(raw_result, search_val) &&
            (!self.value || search_val !== self.value[1])) {
            values.push({label: _.str.sprintf(_t('<em>   Create "<strong>%s</strong>"</em>'),
                    $('<span />').text(search_val).html()), action: function() {
                self._quick_create(search_val);
            }});
        }
        // create...
        values.push({label: _t("<em>   Create and Edit...</em>"), action: function() {
            self._change_int_value(null);
            self._search_create_popup("form", undefined, {"default_name": search_val});
        }});

     } // here endith the hack
```

I want to make this into a module, as editing the source code isn't very maintainable.